# Is a quotient of a solvable group always affine?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

*After several useful comments, I understood that I meant two questions rather than one. Sorry for messing it up, and feel free to answer any of them or vote for closure!*

1. If $G$ is a connected, solvable affine algebraic group (over $\mathbb C$) and $H$ is a closed subgroup, is $G/H$ an affine variety? It is th. 4.3, p. 184 of Hochschild's *Basic theory of algebraic groups and Lie algebras*, thanks to Francois Ziegler's comment.
2. If $G$ is a connected, unipotent affine algebraic group and $H$ is a connected closed subgroup, is $G/H$ an affine space? As $G=\mathbb A^n$ and $H=\mathbb A^k$ as varieties, intuitively, it is a question whether $\mathbb A^n / \mathbb A^k = \mathbb A^{n-k}$. It is true if $H$ is normal, because $G/H$ is connected, unipotent (consists of unipotent elements), and also affine by Ziegler's comment.

For a normal $H$, the second question can also be proven directly: the orbits of a unipotent group $H$ on an affine variety $G$ are closed, therefore the affine quotient $\mathrm{Spec} \; \mathbb C[G]^H$ (where, a priori, the ring is not finitely generated) is geometrical and coincides with $G/H$.

---

*Old version of the question:*

If I am not wrong, any flag variety $G/P$ (where $G$ is semi-simple, $P$ is parabolic) is covered by the orbits of a Borel subgroup $B$, each of which is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^k$ for some $k$.

So I wonder whether every quotient of a connected solvable affine algebraic group by a connected but not necessarily normal subgroup is an affine space?

If not, maybe it is an affine or quasi-affine, variety, or what are the conditions that it is? My motivation is why any spherical variety (that is, a $G$-variety with an open $B$-orbit) is covered by open $B$-stable affine subsets.

Comment: why did this get migrated? for a start, there needs to be a assumption that the initial solvable group is affine algebraic.

Comment: @YCor, why, $G$ is semi-simple, not solvable.

Comment: Do you exclude quotients by cyclic subgroups? These are rarely affine I believe.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, PeterMcNamara, yes, indeed, I meant whether $\mathbb A^n / \mathbb A^k = \mathbb A^{n-k}$ for all structures of solvable group.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I would believe that, in char 0,the quotient by unipotent or reductive (not necessarily connected) subgroups $H$ are always affine. Indeed, say in the second case, $H$ is contained in a Levi factor $D$, we have $G=UD$, and $G/H$ is isomorphic as variety to $U\times (D/H)$ which is affine. This includes the case when $H$ is finite.

Comment: I edited the title as evgeny seems to mean affine in the sense affine space, not affine variety. (In the latter sense, quotients of an irreducible solvable algebraic group over an algebraically closed field by an algebraic subgroup are always affine: Hochschild [(1981, p. 184)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=620024).)

Comment: @YCor What I meant is that a cyclic subgroup may be infinite too. For example, quotient of the multiplicative group by the cyclic subgroup generated by a non-root of 1. After that OP added connectedness requirement on the subgroup, which presumably also means that by subgroups are meant algebraic subgroups.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler The way the title looks now it does not seem to exclude e. g. quotient of the multiplicative group or of, say, a finite solvable group by the trivial subgroup.

Comment: It would be useful to clarify this mess. A torus is not isomorphic to the affine space, so I don"t know how you get this interpretation, and I don't know how you define "quasi-affine" then (isomorphic to open subset of an affine space?). Also I don't see any meaning to the question for non Zariski-closed subgroups.

Comment: Your new question 2 is answered affirmatively by Borel [(1985, Theorem 1.4)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=799451).

Comment: Last comment does not assume $H$ normal. (You have since changed the question again... making it also unclear what "It" stands for in the § following question 2. Roll back for clarity?)

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler, is it better this way? Maybe, you could write it as an answer, so that I can accept it? Thank you for all the help!